# Trigger CRM workflow (Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013)

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamics-crm, workflow, xrm

I need to update few records in an table (tbl_Points). This update needs to happen tree times in a year, at specific time/date. After update i also have to trigger at least one workflow.
How can i achieve that with .Net/C# ? Do i have to create some kind of a plug-in or custom workflow by using XRM sdk? And what about cron job? How can i schedule this process.
I know that this is possible with 'TIBCO Scribe' but i want to use my own .Net/C# skills to achieve this.

- tbl_Points is just custom table
- the workflow that needs to be triggered is basically POST (REST api)

Comment: You can very easily write custom C# console application and schedule it with windows scheduler. To interact with CRM you could use the CRM SDK or go through WebApi.

Comment: And what about triggering other workflows?

Comment: You can trigger workflow using SDK or WebApi

Comment: Power Automate Flow also has [scheduling capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks).